# Show that $\nabla^2(fg)= f\nabla^2g+g\nabla^2f+2\nabla f\cdot\nabla g$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How do I show that

$$\nabla^2(fg) =  f \nabla^2g + g\nabla^2f + 2 \nabla f \cdot \nabla g$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Regards,

Andrew

Answer (score 7):

By definition,

$\nabla^2u = \nabla \cdot \nabla u \tag{1}$

for any sufficiently differentiable function $u$; I guess taking $u \in C^2(R^n, R)$ "suffices".  Then

$\nabla^2(fg)  = \nabla \cdot \nabla (fg), \tag{2}$

and by the product (Leibniz) rule for derivatives, which can easily seen to apply to gradients since in fact

$\dfrac{\partial (fg)}{\partial s} = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial s}g + f \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial s}, \tag{3}$

which holds for any variable $s$ upon which $f$ and $g$ may depend, we have

$\nabla(fg) = f(\nabla g) + g(\nabla f). \tag{4}$

Next, we use the formula

$\nabla \cdot (fX) = \nabla f \cdot X + f \nabla \cdot X, \tag{5}$

which holds for a differentiable function $f$ and  vector field $X$.  It too is a variant of the Leibniz rule, and may easily be verified by working out the relevant expressions in terms of coordinates.  See also [this wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities). Using (4) and (5) together yields

$\nabla \cdot \nabla (fg) = \nabla \cdot (f \nabla g + g\nabla f) = \nabla f \cdot \nabla g + f\nabla^2g + \nabla g \cdot \nabla f  + g \nabla^2f, \tag{6}$

and bringing it all together yields

$\nabla^2(fg) =  f \nabla^2g + g\nabla^2f + 2 \nabla f \cdot \nabla g. \tag{7}$

Hope this helps.  Cheers, and

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 1):

first take the gradient, $\nabla(fg)=f\nabla g+g\nabla f$, then take the divergence, $\nabla\cdot(\nabla[fg])=(\nabla f)\cdot(\nabla g)+f(\nabla\cdot\nabla g)+(\nabla g)\cdot(\nabla f)+g(\nabla\cdot\nabla f)=f\nabla^2 g+g\nabla^2 f+2(\nabla f)\cdot(\nabla g)$