# Laplacian Identity

Tags: derivatives

> Given
>
> $\Delta f :=$ $d^2 f \over d x^2 $ + $d^2 f \over dy^2$,
>
> I have to prove
>
> $\Delta (fg) $=$ f$ * $\Delta$ $g + 2(\nabla f)(\nabla g)+ g$ $\Delta$ $f $.

This was part of one of our exams. The question might be similar to this one

[Laplacian identity.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652730/laplacian-identity),

but we never introduced the general product rule for the Laplacian. Is there another (short) way to show this equation?

**Edit**

I receive

$f_x$ $=$ $df \over dx^2$ $*$ $g  + f$ $*$ $dg \over dx^2$

$f_{xx}$ $=$ ($d^2 f \over dx^2$ $*$ $g$ $+$ $df \over dx^2$ $*$ $dg \over dx^2$) + ($df \over dx^2$ $*$ $dg \over dx^2$ $+$ $f$ $*$ $d^2g \over dx^2$)

$f_y$ $=$ $df \over dy^2$ $*$ $g + f$ $*$ $dg \over dy^2$

$f_{yy}$ $=$ ($d^2 f \over dy^2$ $*$ $g$ $+$ $df \over dy^2$ $*$ $dg \over dy^2$) + ($df \over dy^2$ $*$ $dg \over dy^2$ $+$ $f$ $*$ $d^2g \over dy^2$)

**Edit 2**

Now, I found all the necessary components I need for the equality, but how do I express the gradient in the middle? I would need canonical vectors to put this all toghether. Am I allowed to assume that they exist in this case? What's left is:

$df \over dx^2$ $*$ $dg \over dx^2$ *+* $df \over dx^2$ $*$ $dg \over dx^2$ $+$ $df \over dy^2$ $*$ $dg \over dy^2$ $+$ $df \over dy^2$ $*$ $dg \over dy^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By product rule, begin with $\partial_x fg$.

Then derivate once more : $\partial_{xx}fg$.

The same works with $\partial_y$ and $\partial_{yy}$.

Finally, put everything together.

Comment: I gave it a try - the derivatives first. Would you mind taking a look at it? :-)

Comment: Of course, show me :)

Comment: I editet it in the main post.

Comment: You made a mistake : $\partial_x f$ is ok but $\partial_{xx}f$ is not. Try again (with the product formula again).

Comment: Tried it again, edited in the main post.

Comment: The $f_{xx}, f_{yy}$ in your 1st edit are correct. Now $\nabla f.\nabla g =.. ?$

Comment: Yes, that's why I asked in Edit 2. I guess I'm able to build them by multiplying the remaining terms with the canonical vectors (1, 0) and (0,1).

Comment: I don't know why you are talking about canonical vectors. Just write $\nabla f$ as a vector,  do the same for $\nabla g$ and then do the scalar product :)

Comment: Ohhh, so the remaining terms are the result from the scalar product of $\nabla f$ and $\nabla g$, that's why they equal $2 \nabla f \nabla g$. Got it! :D